# socket.on fire only after page reload

Tags: events, socket.io

My client socket.on doesn't fire after calling the server ( socket.emit ('callserver'). However, when I refresh the page, it works! I'm not sure I understand this correctly. Any idea why this is the case? thanks ahead for any input!

Here's my code for the client:

```
  socket.on('pauseTimeClock', function (data) {
    stopWatchClock.setPausedTime(data.time);
    $('.pauseTime').html(data.time.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span>$1</span>'))
    console.log(stopWatchClock.pausedTime);
});

this.pause = function (stopwatch) {
        this.stopwatch = stopwatch;

        socket.emit('pauseTime');

        this.stopwatch.changeState(this.stopwatch.getPauseState());

    }
```

On the server:

```
socket.on('pauseTime', function () {
//stop broadcasting countDown time
clearInterval(timeinterval);

var pausedTime = moment();

function pauseTimeClock() {

  var timeDiffHour = moment().hour() - pausedTime.hour();
  var timeDiffMinute = moment().minute() - pausedTime.minute();
  var timeDiffSec = moment().second();

  var displayTime = timeDiffHour + ":" + timeDiffMinute + ":" + timeDiffSec;

  socket.broadcast.emit("pauseTimeClock", { time: moment(displayTime, 'hhmm').format('HH:mm') });

}

setInterval(pauseTimeClock, 1000);
```

})

Comment: After monkeying around, I found that socket.broadcast.emit broadcasts to all client except the newly created one, whereas socket.emit broadcasts to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

After monkeying around, I found that socket.broadcast.emit broadcasts to all client except the newly created one, whereas socket.emit broadcasts to everyone.